# Android Create Eraser for canvas without erasing Bitmap Image

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to create an eraser for a canvas and all tutorial links I saw are either broken, too short, or too difficult to understand.

From all I read it seems that I have to create two bitmaps and draw image on one (background) and brush/paint on another (foreground). I do not want to paint over the image cos I need to see the image as I erase.

Can you please tell me how to create this functionality in android in an easy to understand steps. Thanks.

**I do not have any code to show as I am trying to learn this from scratch. Thanks in advance**